# Are old issues of math journals from Belarus Academy of Sciences available online?

Tags: journals, online-resources

I am interested in some papers in Russian which have appeared in the journals "Doklady Akademii Nauk BSSR" and "Vestsi Akademii Navuk BSSR". Are scanned copies available? I could find recent issues (after 2014) (see here: [link](https://vestifm.belnauka.by/jour/issue/archive)), but I would be more interested in certain papers from 1970s.

Comment: Write to the email address at the bottom of https://nasb.gov.by/rus/publications/nauchnye-zhurnaly/vesti_fizmat.php and ask them about the availability (or lack thereof) of scans on their website.  If you have an affiliation with an academic library and want to see specific older articles, the librarians should be able to get copies for you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that for older issues of these journals, there are no scanned copies available online. But depending on your location, a nearby university library might be helpful for getting scans of specific articles. See [worldcat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/4158069).

Another option is the National Library of Belarus. They have an online service which you can use to request scans of items for a reasonable fee.

https://www.nlb.by/en/

I did this successfully for a few older articles from *Vescī Akad. Navuk BSSR*.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single place which contains scanned older papers from these journals. Individual reprints  can be probably requested from the authors, see also arXiv. Also papers in Doklady are usually very short anouncements of papers published later.